# Make old links backwards compatible in express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

You have an application created in express and angular that allows the user to perform a search. The URL is built based upon the search that was just performed. So if you perform a search on “Will” the url looks like `http://localhost.com:9000/search/query?q=Will` Everything works fine but you forgot that the app previously performed searches without the `/query?=` and now all of your old links like `http://localhost.com:9000/search/will` or `http://localhost.com:9000/search/roberto` no longer work.

What would be the correct approach to get the old links working again?

Should you use JavaScript on the frontend to look for /query?= missing in the URL and add after the search path but before the queried text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be easier to do a redirect on the Express back-end.

Say your code for the `/search/query` path is initially like this :

```
app.get("/search/query", function (req, res) {
    // Do your query validation and fetch your search result.
    // Here, I just check if a query value was given or not for the q param.
    // I recommend you use better ways to check for empty queries. 
    // (ex: lodash's `isEmpty()` function)
    if (req.query.q) {
        // Serve the page !
        res.send("What you want to render if the search result finds something.");
    }
    else {
        // Return an error !
        res.status(404).send("Nothing was found with the criterias entered.");
    }
});
```

This is probably similar to what you have. Now, here is the answer to your question, based on the initial implementation above :

```
app.get("/search/query", function (req, res, next) {
    // Check if a query value was given AND if the value isn't equal to "query".
    // The later condition is to prevent infinite loops.
    if (req.query.q && req.query.q !== "query") {
        // Redirect using the value assigned to the q query param.
        res.redirect("/search/" + req.query.q);
    }
    else {
        // Since there is no query parameter named `q` in the request,
        // we can be sure that `query` reffers to a search term.
        next();
    }
});

app.param("srchterm", function (req, res, next, value) {
    // Check, for example, if the value isn't empty.
    if (value) {
        // Do your query validation and fetch your search result HERE.
        // Add those results in an array in the res.locals object.
        // Those results can be used later.
        res.locals.results = ["all", "your", "search", "results"];
    }
    next();
});

app.get("/search/:srchterm", function (req, res) {
    console.log("another blah");
    // We don't need to fetch the data here anymore, since it's handled by the param parser above!
    // However, it's still necessary to check if the search gave back some results.
    if (res.locals.results) {
        // Serve the results !
        res.send("A total of " + res.locals.results.length + " results were found for " + req.params['srchterm']);
    }
    else {
        // Return an error !
        res.status(404).send("Nothing was found with the criterias entered.");
    }
});
```

So from now on, every query using `/search/query?q=123` will redirect towards `/search/123`. It even lets you use `query` as the search term!

Comment: Your solution does not resolve the issue. The redirect is supposed to go to `/search/query?=123` not towards `/search/123` while you do have useful code. I found another way around this issue.

Comment: I know, I figured out right after answering his solution that it was the complete opposite. Call me an ass if you want, but I do believe if the question was asked in a less confusing way, I could've answered correctly; Usually, you define the initial status of your program, then mention what you're trying to achieve, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regex and redirect

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var searchRegEx = /\/search/g;
    var searchedTerm = req.originalUrl.replace(searchRegEx, '');
    var queryPath = req.originalUrl.match(/\/query[?]q=/);
    if(!queryPath) {
        var regexSlash = /\//g;
        res.redirect('query?q=' + searchedTerm.replace(regexSlash, ''));
    }
    else {
        next();
    } 
});
```